# How can I shape an image with css?

Tags: html, css

[image: reference]

How i can do this with CSS, I was trying to do it 
 with `clip-paht` but it is not supported by Mozilla FireFox!

```
.div{
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(1% 100%, 54% 85%, 67% 81%, 78% 79%, 91% 80%, 100% 82%, 100% 0, 0 0);
  clip-path: polygon(1% 100%, 54% 85%, 67% 81%, 78% 79%, 91% 80%, 100% 82%, 100% 0, 0 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox versions 52 and before does not support polygon in clip-path, but there is a workaround for it: you can use a `svg` element with a clipPath in your HTML as following:

```css
.div{
  background: blue; width:100%; height:200px; 

  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(1% 100%, 54% 85%, 67% 81%, 78% 79%, 91% 80%, 100% 82%, 100% 0, 0 0);

  clip-path: url("#myPolygon"); /*Firefox*/

  clip-path: polygon(1% 100%, 54% 85%, 67% 81%, 78% 79%, 91% 80%, 100% 82%, 100% 0, 0 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="div">&nbsp;</div>
  
<svg width="0" height="0">
  <clipPath id="myPolygon" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
    <polygon points=".01 1.00, .54 .85, .67 .81, .78 .79, .91 .80, 1.00 .82, 1.00 0, 0 0" />
  </clipPath>
</svg>
```

Note that as your coordinates are in percentage, we have to use the `clipPathUnits = "objectBoundingBox"` property and define numbers in 0 to 1 range (for example, 54% should be written as 0.54)

Comment: thanks bro, :D i needed do that. now i will do the rest for trying to do the shape less square

Answer (score 0):

As this is experimental property, You need to use "-moz-clip-path" to work in firefox.